# Sunspot/Solr : Searching with multiple fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, solr, sunspot

What is the way to use Sunspot/Solr with mutiple fields ?
It works fine with a simple form, as explained in this screencast : http://railscasts.com/episodes/278-search-with-sunspot

You can see my draft which doesn't work :

*product.rb*

```
searchable do
  text :address
  text :model
  text :category
end
```

*products_controller.rb*

```
  def search
    @search = Sunspot.search(Product) do
      fulltext params[:address]
        with(:model, params[:model]) if params[:model].present?
        with(:category, params[:category]) if params[:category].present?
    end
    @products = @search.results
  end
```

*products/search.html.erb*

```
  <%= form_tag products_search_path, :method => :get do %>
    <div class="field">
        <%= label_tag "Address ?" %>
        <%= select_tag :address, "<option>he</option><option>ho</option>".html_safe %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= label_tag "Model ?" %>
        <%= text_field_tag :model, params[:model] %>
        <%#= select_tag :model, "<option>hi</option><option>ha</option>".html_safe %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= label_tag "Category ?" %>
        <%= text_field_tag :category, params[:category] %>
    </div>
    <div id="buttonSearch"><%= submit_tag "Search" %></div>
  <% end %>
```

**The error :**

```
Sunspot::UnrecognizedFieldError (No field configured for Product with name 'model'):
  app/controllers/products_controller.rb:99:in `block in search'
  app/controllers/products_controller.rb:97:in `search'
```

Thanks guys for your helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only want this (below)... You only want full text, which will search across all fields you define in searchable... I used "s" as the param name

```
@search = Sunspot.search(Product) do
  fulltext(params[:s])
end
```

Comment: This doesn't do what @remink was asking, which was to scope the query by `:model` and `:category`.

Answer (score 1):

If you setup `product.rb` like so (specifying `:model` and `:category` as non-fulltext string fields that can be used for scoping), then your search code should work verbatim.

```
# product.rb
searchable do
  text :address
  string :model
  string :category
end
```